# If you know why something happened, and why something didn't happen...

Tags: statistics, chaos-theory

I'm not a mathematician, so go easy. I dropped out of high school. But I'm a programmer / logician / writer of algorithms. And I'm currently engaged in one of my most complex projects to date, which involves building up something like Markov chains within one another to lead people to find unexpected, complex results out of their own psychological preferences.

I'm raising this question not because I need help with my project, but because I stumbled on an unexpected feature of my data, and then had a corresponding dream about it.

The feature I stumbled on was that it's quite easy to record all the events and conditions leading up to a happening, but it's quite another thing to record all the ones that *didn't* lead to it, let alone all the ones that *didn't lead to something not happening*. And let's not forget all the ones that didn't lead to something not happening which caused a whole chain of other things not to happen.

**The dream**
In the dream, K[0] is a set of things that had never been imagined happening. K[1] is a set of things that you could imagine, because they diverged from the chain of events at some point where you could still conceive of their results. But they didn't actually happen. K[2] is the much smaller set of things that actually did happen. From K[2] you can begin to infer K[1]. As soon as you imagine something from K[0], it becomes part of K[1]. For all intents and purposes, K[0] is infinite, even after you imagine parts out of it. K[1] is only limited by your imagination, and K[2] is the reality upon which your imagination is based.

So in this dream, K[1] acts as a kind of thicker or thinner membrane around reality, describing the contour of K[0] which most closely match K[2]. Depending on how much of K[0] you can imagine and reference to something happening in K[2].

What I'm interested in is, is what is the relationship between these sets?

For example, how can you prove that K[1] doesn't exist until you imagine it, and that K[0] is still unknown even though you can pull an element out randomly, by imagining it, and insert it into K[1]?

Apologies if this makes no sense, just a human brain trying to make order out of chaos.

Comment: Sounds like a question for philosophy stackexchange.

Comment: On the contrary, I like it here. It's a nice change of pace from all the 'Let $X$ be a space' and 'Compute Galois group $G$'. Might need some extra tags though.

Comment: thank you...? It's a weird confluence between a philosophical question and a programmer's question which is, practically, "how much data should I store about what didn't happen". So I thought that probably only pure mathematicians would be able to give me a lever to understand the mass and width that boulder and how best to approach it...

Comment: Quite confusing that you want to store "data about what did not happen". Only one idea what you might mean comes in my mind : Estimating a probability of an event that did not (yet) happen based on how often it could have happened (but did not).

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer On the one hand, I agree. On the other hand ,  a mathematical question should have some rigorousness which I cannot see here.

Comment: @Peter Okay. Apologies for the lack of rigor. Imagine you have a pool of "events" which can occur. Each of those has a set of conditions which trigger them, based upon prior occurrences of other events or combinations thereof. Some "events" give the subject a choice between various outcomes, and these outcomes are then fed back to the other event loops to modify their probability of occurring. In every case as you tick through whether or not an event occurs, you reject the majority of possible occurrences...

Comment: ...the reasons for rejecting them are multifarious; not enough other input. Too much of something or too little of another. To simply parse the occurrences for a first run requires a lot of computational power and a fair amount of storage. To parse every branch off a single random run requires exponential amounts of CPU and storage. But to record every time a branch and its branches were simply ignored would overwhelm such a system.

Comment: So in this light I could ask, what is the trade-off between the usefulness of knowing what didn't happen and why, versus the cost of calculating every  outcome in the system; but I can figure that out. What I'm wondering is hard to make rigorous because it's not that simple... Here's another way: *does the cost increase only when you begin to calculate the possibility as a result of the [now known] outcome?*

Comment: Sorry to go on. Let's say a subject asks "what if X didn't happen at step 13 out of 100". That's easy enough to reproduce as a new chain of probabilities. But when analyzing the entire structure there is this -- *dark matter* mass of such inconclusive chains which is *so much larger* than the probable chains themselves, that it makes me wonder which is not more important. Because that enormous set is the inverse of the limited set derived. You could reproduce either from the other. But *some* of that set can be guessed.